# MongoDB inserting field that is a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So I'm trying to insert a new field into `MongoDB`, and whilst it will accept my `Javascript` variable as data, it won't accept it as a new field name:

```
function appendInformation(question, answer) {
    Sessions.update({ _id: Id }, { question : answer });
}
```

It inserts the correct answer, but is listed in the doc as `question: {answer}` not `{question} : {answer}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `$set` to update the `Session` document with a new field.

```
function appendInformation(question, answer) {
    var qa = { };
    qa[question] = answer;
    Sessions.update({ _id: Id }, { $set : qa });
}
```

`$set` [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-specific-fields-in-a-document)

```
> db.so.remove()
> var qa={"question 1" : "the answer is 1"};
> db.so.insert(qa);
> db.so.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520136af3c5438af60de6398"),
               "question 1" : "the answer is 1" }
> var qa2={"question 2" : "the answer is 2"};
> db.so.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("520136af3c5438af60de6398")}, { $set : qa2 })
> db.so.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520136af3c5438af60de6398"), 
               "question 1" : "the answer is 1",
               "question 2" : "the answer is 2" }
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know this, just started working with nosql a couple weeks ago. +1.